# Magento Custom Form in create order page

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I want to add custom form in create order page in magento admin side.As per my client request i was trying to create measurements form and wanna store data.I am new to magento.Please help me.Attached image for ref.[image]
Already posted same question in [Magento Stack Exchange](http://magento.stackexchange.com) [My Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91375/magento-custom-form-in-create-order-page)

I created block in `layout/sales.xml` file and created `customform.phtml`.Now i'm able to display custom form.Now i want to store data along with other data in this page.

Comment: can some one help me?

Answer (score 0):

You should add a table (with `order id` as `foreign key`) or a new text field to `order sales_flat_order` table.

After that, you are able to catch this event: `sales_order_save_after`

Inside this function, you can save data to the custom table or custom field you added.

good luck.

Comment: can you explain in detail?I have created separate table manually  to store my form data.I was able to display custom form here.I'm not sure exactly how to save it along with other data.

Comment: There is no such function.I found `sales_order_save_after` in config.xml file.There i just added my method name